# Is there a way to change encryption scheme from AES to FHE without data leakage?

Tags: aes, homomorphic-encryption

So let's say that we have encrypted some data using symmetric encryption in this case AES. And we want to change it to homomorphic encryption but without decrypting the data and encrypting it again using FHE. Do you know if this is possible in any way?

Comment: It's FHE, so encrypt the key, encrypt the AES ciphertext, decrypt homomorphically. It probably won't be particularly efficient.

Comment: @Maeher Can I do that? I thought about it but I wasn't sure. Thank you so much. Regarding the efficiency you are right but I would like to give it a try!

Comment: Decrypting a ciphertext c with a key k ist just some computation on (c,k). Since FHE allows you to perform any computation on encrypted inputs, yes it's possible. All you need is an encrypted version of $k$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about FHE (as stated in the title, but not in the question body) then yes, this is possible.

Encrypt the symmetric key $k$ that was used to originally encrypt the data as well as the symmetric ciphertext $c$ under the FHE public key. Then homomorphically evaluate the decryption circuit of the symmetric encryption scheme on those ciphertexts. By the correctness of the FHE scheme the result will be a ciphertext encrypting the original data under the FHE public key.

Comment: Do you even have to encrypt the cipher text? Most (all?) FHE ciphers can operate on mixed inputs.

Comment: @mikeazo That's probably true in practice.

Comment: Thanks @Maeher. I also updated the body of my question to FHE.